# Visual Studio Output window for Mac

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

In Visual Studio on Windows I have a nice Output window showing me what the program is doing and what errors occur, especially with Blazor. How can I open this on Visual Studio for Mac or on Rider? I have clicked and looked a lot but i could not find it.
[image: The output Window i am looking for]

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac shows output this information in its Application Output window for ASP.NET Core projects. This window will be created/opened when you debug or run your project. Console projects will console output information to a Terminal window.